# Pdo table prefix

Tags: php, pdo

I relied on the Pdo Api when I built my web application that turned out to be a quite large one, now I need to be able to prefix the tables such as prefix_tablename... How should I approach this?

- Make a wrapper (Time consuming, hard to do etc).
- Add a str_replace
  after every query, yes it sounds stupid...

  $stmt = $db->prepare("query FROM :prefix:table")...

etc.

Extend the PDO class and hack some way around there?

Is there any magical feature that I perhaps have missed that can help me achieve this...?

Comment: Option 3: rethink your database design (i.e. do you really need to prefix your tables?)

Comment: Why do you need to prefix your tables?

Answer (score 0):

It is not the answer that you want at all, but i would recommend you to use an *DBAL* (*Data Base Abstraction Layer*). In this case, i would recommend [Doctrine](http://doctrine-project.org/). If you used it, all you would have to change are the table names INSIDE the `entities`. Your code would be exactly the same.

Anyway, good luck. There is no easy answer besides *not* changing the database

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the PDO class and use the magica method [`__call()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to check the `prepare()` method being called and replace the ::prefix:: in the query text. Should be smth like this:

```
class PrefixedPDO extends PDO {

   /**
    * @link http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call
    */
   public function __call($name, $arguments)
   {
      // according to [this](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php) - query should be in the args
      if ($name === 'prepare') {
          // check for the ::prefix:: in the query text (use params for that)
      }
   }

}
```

You will also need to change your PDO init to the new class - `PrefixedPDO()`;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't `__call` only called when a method could not be found. In your example, the custom class extends PDO, so the magic `__call` is never called when somebody accesses the `prepare` method.